# Springboot integration with RestEasy and deploying to Jboss server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, resteasy

I wanted to integrate Spring boot with RestEasy. 
I started using Paypal Springboot starter for the same by referring the [link](https://github.com/paypal/resteasy-spring-boot)

I have added paypal resteasy dependency as mentioned in the above link.
But while deploying to Jboss server i am getting error below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NotImplementedYetException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:131)
```

Can someone please suggest me the best way to integrate Springboot with RestEasy?

Comment: if you are using spring boot, shouldn't the jar already have an embedded server? why do you need to deploy to another server?

Comment: I agree, it works fine for the Spring boot Embedded server. But, in our project, we have Jboss server in Production and we have restirction to deploy on Jboss server only..

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be two separate questions here: how to integrate RESTEasy, and how to deploy to JBoss.

**RESTEasy:** The Paypal starter for RESTEasy that you mentioned has been transferred to a new home. https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-spring-boot/blob/master/mds/USAGE.md
The latest versions works well. (I don't know what changed since the version you used.)

**JBoss:**
Converting a self-hosting Spring Boot application to one that runs on JBoss requires a few steps, and it's not clear from your writeup which of those changes you've already made.

1) In your pom.xml, change packaging from jar to war.

2) Also in pom.xml, exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat from any dependencies that try to bring it in. Typically this is spring-boot-starter-web, but if you are using resteasy-spring-boot-starter you would exclude from that instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

3) Change `main` class and make it extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

4) Also in `main` override the `configure` method. (Some articles omit this step- it has to do with making sure your components are scanned correctly so there might be ways to configure a project so it is optional.)

```
public class NameOfMyMainClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(NameOfMyMainClass.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NameOfMyMainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

These steps are written up in detail here: https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/08/06/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/

In theory that's all you need. But in practice, I never got it working (Spring Boot 2.0.4, JBoss 7.1.)

First issue: Spring Boot 2 apparently requires JBoss 7. I didn't learn this until after I'd wasted some time with JBoss 6.
Second issue: Even after upgrading the server, my JAX-RS beans never worked. According to the following article, JBoss 7.1.1 does not integrate cleanly and requires some additional workarounds: https://ilya-murzinov.github.io/articles/spring-boot-jboss/

There are articles that claim success, but note they tend to be using Wildfly, not JBoss. (It's also possible JBoss 7.0 didn't have all these problems.) So if you are following one of these articles, make sure they are using versions of Spring Boot and JBoss that you can use.